# Show plot according to argument with patchwork package

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, patchwork

I'm trying to write a function with `patchwork` package in which plots are displayed according to the arguments passed in the function. I tried the approach below, setting objects not passed in the function as NULL. However, it only works if the first object is different from NULL. Any thoughts?

```r
# 1. PACKAGES

library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

# 2. DATA

data = starwars

# 3. FUNCTION

plot_people = function (homeworld = c("Tatooine", "Naboo", "Alderaan")) {

  p1 = if (is.element("Tatooine", homeworld)) {

    data %>%
    filter(homeworld == "Tatooine") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = mass, y = height,
               label = ifelse(species == "Human", name, NA))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_label()

  } else {

    NULL
  }

  p2 = if (is.element("Naboo", homeworld)) {

    data %>%
      filter(homeworld == "Naboo") %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = mass, y = height,
                 label = ifelse(species == "Human", name, NA))) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_label()

  } else {

    NULL
  }

  p3 = if (is.element("Alderaan", homeworld)) {

    data %>%
      filter(homeworld == "Alderaan") %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = mass, y = height,
                 label = ifelse(species == "Human", name, NA))) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_label()

  } else {

    NULL
  }

  # how to write this line in order to plot only objects in homeworld argument?
  p1 + p2 + p3

}

# 4. RESULTS

plot_people(homeworld = c("Naboo", "Tatooine"))
```

[image]

```r
plot_people(homeworld = c("Naboo", "Alderaan"))
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to run the same code for each element of `homeworld`, you can iterate across it with [`purrr::map`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) (or `lapply`, if you prefer). This returns a list with an element for each iteration, here containing a plot (like `p1`, `p2`, etc.). This list can be [`reduce`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/reduce.html)d (or `Reduce`d) to iteratively combine each element with `+`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

plot_people = function (homeworld = c("Tatooine", "Naboo", "Alderaan")) {

    plots <- map(homeworld, function(hw){
        starwars %>%
            filter(homeworld == hw) %>%
            ggplot(aes(x = mass, y = height,
                       label = ifelse(species == "Human", name, NA))) +
            geom_point() +
            geom_label()
    })

    reduce(plots, `+`)
}

plot_people(homeworld = c("Naboo", "Tatooine"))
```

[image]

```r
plot_people(homeworld = c("Naboo", "Alderaan"))
```

[image]

Alternatively, instead of `` reduce(plots, `+`) ``, you could write `wrap_plots(plots)`, using the `wrap_plots()` function from patchwork which accepts a list of plots. The results are the same.

More generally, you should consider facetting before resorting to patchwork:

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot_people = function (homeworld = c("Tatooine", "Naboo", "Alderaan")) {
    starwars %>%
        filter(homeworld %in% !!homeworld) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = mass, y = height,
                   label = ifelse(species == "Human", name, NA))) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_label() + 
        facet_wrap(~homeworld)
}

plot_people(homeworld = c("Naboo", "Tatooine"))
```

[image]

```r
plot_people(homeworld = c("Naboo", "Alderaan"))
```

[image]

Note you get nice panel strip labels identifying which planet is which for free with this approach.

Comment: Awesome, thanks (again)! I'll give it a try on both approaches!